# Declare cursor and stored procedure in phpmyadmin mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my problem I get all this error for declare variable and cursor, anyone know what is happen ? and other thing is this work for me, help please

[image]

[image]

Comment: INSERT INTO mensajes(Usu_Id,Men_Msj,Men_Estado,Men_Tipo,Men_Mail_Enviado,Cen_Codigo) SELECT Usu_Id,message,'1','1',mail,centroid FROM equ_usu WHERE Equ_Id=equid   THIS WAS MY SOLUTION, THIS MAKE THE SAME THINK

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version do you have?

Comment: i don´t remember because i finish that job, but whit the update to the last version, all problems are gone

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring some closure to this, it appears to have been caused by an old version of phpMyAdmin. There were some problems with the parser library which were fixed, and that explains why when you upgraded the problem went away.